# Poner un sitio de laravel 10 en mantenimiento sin usar la terminal

Tags: laravel

¿es posible poner un sitio de laravel sin tener que usar la terminal?. Quiero en el panel administrativo poner una opción para marcar o desmarcar cuando quisiera que el sitio se ponga en mantenimiento, pero no encuentro la forma, solo he visto posible ponerlo en mantenimiento desde la terminal.

Comment: Podrías hacer un `CronJob` que ejecute el comando de la terminal y lo podrías ligar a un botón. [Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#dispatching-jobs)

Comment: Si yo se que creando un cronjob se logra, pero lo que queria saber si exitia alguna otra forma q no sea usando cronjob ni la consola, ni tener que hacer un modulo de mantenimiento desde 0